# Moving to Australia as a couple: Visa requirement

Tags: visa, australia

My partner got a promotion proposition and we might be moving to Melbourne in the upcoming 6 months (I know it makes it short for me). I would like to know what type of Visa and requirement I should look for to be able to move with her there.

More details:

- We are in a *de facto* relationship;
- We are EU-citizen (Bulgaria and France), living in the Netherlands;
- And if I cannot apply for anything "using" our relationship, I have a MSc in computer science, with little work experience, and could work for jobs on the [SOL](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Work/Skills-assessment-and-assessing-authorities/skilled-occupations-lists/SOL)

Comment: It'll depend on a lot of factors, how long you want to spend there, how many children you have, points, etc.  Have you looked into any yourself?